# How to get data from input in ASP.net MVC3 c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code in my NewMember.cshtml View file:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New Member";
}

<div id="newForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="first"><label title="Date" runat="server">Date</label></td>
            <td class="second"><input id="DateBox" value="test"" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="first"><label title="FirstName" runat="server">First Name</label></td>
            <td class="second"><input id="FirstNameBox" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="first"><label title="LastName" runat="server">Last Name</label></td>
            <td class="second"><input id="LastNameBox" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="first"><label title="DOB" runat="server">Date of Birth</label></td>
            <td class="second"><input id="DOBBox" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

And my Controller file for this contains the following method:

```
public ActionResult NewMember()
{
    return View();
}
```

I am using Microsoft's SQL Server 2008 to hold these information. I know how to make a query to the database using c#, but I don't understand how to get the inputted data from the View file to the Controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: a little bit more information - I've been looking around the internet for this problem and I seen some uses Javascript. Unfortunately, I do not know any javascript, so is there a way to do this without using javascript?

Comment: runat=server is for WebForms, not MVC. Let's take a look to any  [MVC example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3).

Comment: you should be using the helpers included in MVC http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper_methods(v=vs.108).aspx. else you will have to use javascript and give your fields an id

Comment: @Adriano, Many thanks for the link. However, I have looked at the website before, but most of the examples uses aspx files while I uses cshtml files (Razor). Is there any other examples or link you can send? Thanks

Comment: @Danny actually that example **is** with Razor...

Comment: @Danny You need BeginForm method, look tutorial from Adriano comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

Comment: Thanks for all the advice and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want ajax calls, you don't have to use javascript

Give input elements a name in your form and lose the *runat="server"*

View:

```
<form id="newForm" method="POST" action="@Url.Action("NewMember", "CONTROLLER NAME")">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><label title="Date">Date</label></td>
        <td class="second"><input id="DateBox" value="test"" name="date" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><label title="FirstName">First Name</label></td>
        <td class="second"><input id="FirstNameBox" name="fname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><label title="LastName">Last Name</label></td>
        <td class="second"><input id="LastNameBox" name="lname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><label title="DOB" >Date of Birth</label></td>
        <td class="second"><input id="DOBBox" name="birth" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Then in your controller create an action to handle posts:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewMember(string date, string fname, string lname, string birth)
{
   return View();
}
```

Hope this helps!